# Record user desktop screen and save on server

Tags: flash, apache-flex, desktop-recording

I am developing a web application where I need a feature which should be able to record my user's desktop activities and stream the recorded video to my server. I am not getting any idea about how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

that cant be done from a web application, because its a security risk.. you need to create a native application for this. (See join.me for example)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: it is an answer. it cannot be done. if this would be enabled, any website could track private user information. it can be done with an app that uses winapi, etc. but not from a flex webapp.